Trigering workflow using workflow_run
I'm working with two GitHub Actions workflow files: one for a SHARED-PROJECT and one for a DEPENDANT-PROJECT. I'm trying to trigger the DEPENDANT-PROJECT workflow using workflow_run whenever there's a change in SHARED-PROJECT. However, I'm encountering an issue where the DEPENDANT-PROJECT workflow is not being triggered when there's a change in the SHARED-PROJECT.
Here are the workflow files:
SHARED-PROJECT-CI-BUILD
name: SHARED-PROJECT-CI-BUILD

on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - master
    paths:
      - 'shared-project/**'

jobs:
  ci-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event_name == 'push'
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Source
        id: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Build Master
        id: buildmaster
        run: |
          ./shared-project/publish.sh

DEPENDANT-PROJECT-CI-BUILD
name: DEPENDANT-PROJECT-CI-BUILD

on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - master
    paths:
      - 'dependant-project/**'
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["SHARED-PROJECT-CI-BUILD"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  ci-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || github.event_name == 'workflow_run'
    steps: 
      - name: Checkout Source
        id: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}

      - name: Build Master
        id: buildmaster
        run: |
          ./dependant-project/publish.sh

What might I be missing in my configuration that's preventing the DEPENDANT-PROJECT workflow from triggering when there's a change in SHARED-PROJECT?
Thanks for your help!

The above setup will trigger DEPENDANT-PROJECT-CI-BUILD workflow when SHARED-PROJECT-CI-BUILD workflow completes on a branch. However, GitHHub will look for DEPENDANT-PROJECT-CI-BUILD workflow on the default branch of the repo - master in your case. Based on the fact that DEPENDANT-PROJECT-CI-BUILD workflow is not being triggered, it simply is not present on the master branch or it does not have workflow_run trigger on the master branch.
Once the DEPENDANT-PROJECT-CI-BUILD workflow is running, you do checkout the same branch that was running on the SHARED-PROJECT-CI-BUILD. However, for this to work as you intended, the  DEPENDANT-PROJECT-CI-BUILD workflow must be initially present on the master branch with the workflow_run trigger.

You're right; I missed that in the documentation. Is there any way I can test this in PRs before merging to the master branch? Even after merging the workflow_run change to the master branch, it won't trigger when there's a change in the shared project on any branch, correct? This will only work on the master branch. Is there another way I can trigger other workflows, even in PR branches?

It will trigger, however GitHub will execute the workflow from the master branch. If the workflow is quite static and the logic is delegated to the scripts, the scripts will be from the PR branch.
